# How to design and pass information in multiple Amazon.NextIntent chains for Alexa / Amazon Echo

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

Hi currently thinking about a good design to manage multiple output chains in an Alexa skill. For example if I start with one intent called "yesterday" and another one called "today". I want to pass this information (is it "yesterday" I started the chain with or "today") to a NextIntent chain.

Whats the best way to pass information between intents?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out here https://developer.amazon.com/de/blogs/alexa/post/f167aa0f-8abe-4602-b985-65118b3032ca/code-deep-dive-slots-and-session-attributes-in-the-ask-sdk-for-node-js how to do it.

I was searching for **session attributes**

These can be used like this

1) The first intent I called to start the chain:

```
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
      return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
          && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'BesterAutorIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
      try {
        const speechOutput = "Ich könnte dir sagen wer der beste Autor ist, aber ich muss erst HR fragen ob ich darf";

        const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
        attributes.kaesebrot = "kaesebrot"
        handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(attributes)

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(speechOutput)
          .reprompt()
          .withSimpleCard(defaulttext.SKILL_NAME, speechOutput)
          .getResponse();

      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
  };
```

In there you can I set an attribute called kaesebrot to be a session attribute:

```
const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
attributes.kaesebrot = "kaesebrot"
handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(attributes)
```

Later in another function you can get it like this

```
let counter = 0;

const NextIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
      const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
      return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.NextIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        try {
            counter = counter + 1;

            const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
            speechOutput = counter + " TEST " + attributes.kaesebrot;

            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(speechOutput)
                .reprompt()
                .withSimpleCard(defaulttext.SKILL_NAME, speechOutput)
                .getResponse();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Tobi's answer is good.

I am using sdk v1 and the code to keep attributes on dynamoDB is like this:

```
    exports.handler = function( event, context, callback ) {
        const alexa = Alexa.handler( event, context );
        alexa.dynamoDBTableName = "alexaTable";
        alexa.registerHandlers( handlers );
        alexa.execute();
    };
...
    const handlers = {
...
        "AMAZON.NextIntent": function () {
            console.log( "AMAZON.NextIntent: " + this.attributes.index );
         }
...
}
```

A dynamodb table "alexaTable" will be created the first time the lambda function is invoked and will store and retrieve the attributes automatically.
In the above example "index" is an attribute carried over from a previous intent.

Table schema consists of a key and a field.

1. Key: userId, alexa skill user id
2. Field: mapAttr, JSON structured attributes
   but it is self-managed by the alexa-sdk.

This post can help further
https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/648c46a1-b491-49bc-902d-d05ecf5c65b4/tips-on-state-management-at-three-different-levels

Answer (score 0):

[SessionAttributes](https://developer.amazon.com/de/blogs/alexa/post/f167aa0f-8abe-4602-b985-65118b3032ca/code-deep-dive-slots-and-session-attributes-in-the-ask-sdk-for-node-js) is a way to persist state across intents but there's a new feature jsut out of the oven to specifically chain intents and pass slot values.

It's called Intent Chaining and you can see more here:
https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/9ffdbddb-948a-4eff-8408-7e210282ed38/intent-chaining-for-alexa-skill

Intent chaining allows your skill code to start dialog management from any intent, including the LaunchRequest. You can chain into any of your custom intents as long as your interaction model has a dialog model.

For example, from YesterdayIntent, in the response builder you would do:

```
handlerInput.responseBuilder.addDelegateDirective({
    name: 'TodayIntent',
    confirmationStatus: 'NONE',
    slots: {} // the slot values to pass go here
 })
```